# Practices to prevent/control image content

Tags: version-control

Dead code is easily recognised and eliminated by having code reviews, however, when it comes to images - unused images still get into our version control. Is there any clean way of organising graphic content so that a direct correlation exists between web pages and image files?

In our current project, we use create master PNG files then export the required layers for development purpose. Recently I figured out that there is some bloat in the images folder. Doing a search for image names in code helps but it is very painful when it  needs to be done for hundred odd images. So asking the forum for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You could walk the website with a crawler (like wget) and remove any image not touched (i.e. not listed in your logs.)

A quicker way would be to just dump all the image file names found in your code.

```
grep -o -e \w*?\.png    (caution: untested regex)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 1 step build and can test for dead links, then you should be able to write a script that would do a clean checkout of the project, delete a single image and build & test the project. If no errors pop up the image is unneeded.

It would take a long time to run (maybe days depending on the project size) but that's computer time, not man-hours.